# Can I enforce a linker warning/error when multiple symbol definitions are present?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, ld, elf

Assume I have `liba.so` and `libb.so` and both define a symbol `foo`. For better comprehension, let's assume both libraries are compiled from a single file each and `foo` is a C function like this:

```
int foo(void); // returns 1 for liba.so and 2 for libb.so
```

If I now introduce an executable that links to these two libraries, the link order will determine which of the two implementations is taken (in general [breadth-first](https://akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)).

If `liba` and `libb` were object files, I would get a linker error about multiple definitions instead.

Is there a way to enforce this behavior (detection of multiple definitions and emitting a warning/error) for shared objects as well? I would like to be able to detect duplicates during link time already and not be surprised with erroneous behavior during run time.

In case it is not possible, can you explain why?

Comment: Do you mean 'during link time of the executable that uses both libraries'? If so, even if it's possible (I don't know right now) it wouldn't help if _after linking it_ you add something to one of the libraries which is a duplicate t the other one. So I think in general it's best to define all global symbols of a lib with an appropriate prefix, mo matter if it's a static or a dynamlic lib

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yes, I'm practically running `gcc -o prog main.o -L. -la -lb`, where the order of `-la -lb` vs. `-lb -la` determines the function that is called. I'm working on a legacy code base where I want to merge two executables into one. I've transformed the former executables into shared libraries and the new executable simply consumes them and acts as a driver. I'd like to see which symbols are duplicated (by means of warnings/errors), similar to what I would have gotten if I had attempted to link all object files (namely, "multiple definition" errors).

Answer (score 1):

> In case it is not possible

It is not possible -- UNIX shared libraries are *designed* to work this way. In addition, symbol redefinition is *very* common. If there was a linker warning to signal such redefinition, you would get a lot of intentional "false positives".

> can you explain why?

UNIX shared libraries are designed to work the "same way" archive libraries do. If you had `liba.a` and `libb.a`, each defining `foo()`, you wouldn't expect a warning or an error and the version of `foo()` you would actually get would depend on the library order.

When using `liba.so` and `libb.so` the behavior is *exactly* the same.

**Update:**

> I still don't understand *why* I cannot enforce the linker to emit a warning.

You can. All you have to do is modify the linker to implement the warning you want, and then use the modified linker.

The answer above explains why no existing UNIX linker implements this warning (it would be useless to most developers and produce "false positives").

Comment: I still don't understand _why_ I cannot enforce the linker to emit a warning. While it's good to know that shared libraries are supposed to work similar to static libraries, the question remains the same: Why can't I enforce a linker warning if I'm linking against libraries that have duplicated symbols? I'm not saying it should be the default (for the same reasons that you mentioned), but _an option to do it_ would be nice to have.

Comment: @andreee I've updated the answer.